# Triple fault on changing CR0 to start protected mode

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, 32-bit, osdev

I'm currently developing an operating system. I'm using VMWare to emulate it. I was debugging by using `int 0x16` on every line and I found out that when I switch `CR0`, the Protected Mode Switch, to 1, it just triple faults. Here's stage 2 of the kernel loader:

```
bits    16
org 0x500
jmp main
%include "stdio.inc"        
%include "Gdt.inc"          
%include "A20.inc"
%include "Fat12.inc"
%include "common.inc"
LoadingMsg db "Please Wait . . .", 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x00
msgFailure db 0x0D, 0x0A, "Can't find Krnl. Press any key to retry", 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0A, 0x00
main:
    cli         
    xor ax, ax  
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ax, 0x9000
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0xFFFF
    sti         
    call    InstallGDT      
    call    EnableA20_KKbrd_Out
    mov si, LoadingMsg
    call    Puts16 ; nuts61
    jmp    EnterKernel
    mov ah, 0
    int     0x16    
    int     0x19    
    cli             
    hlt
EnterKernel:
    cli 
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 1
    mov cr0, eax ; <= here is the damn triple fault
    jmp CODE_DESC:KernelC
bits 32
KernelC:
    mov     ax, DATA_DESC
    mov     ds, ax
    mov     ss, ax
    mov     es, ax
    mov     esp, 90000h
CopyImage:
    mov eax, dword [ImageSize]
    movzx   ebx, word [bpbBytesPerSector]
    mul ebx
    mov ebx, 4
    div ebx
    cld
    mov    esi, IMAGE_RMODE_BASE
    mov edi, IMAGE_PMODE_BASE
    mov ecx, eax
    rep movsd
jmp CODE_DESC:IMAGE_PMODE_BASE
cli
hlt
```

I marked the error location. I also found some of the VMWare triple fault logs:

```
2016-01-14T17:30:00.613+01:00| vcpu-0| I120: Triple fault.
2016-01-14T17:30:00.613+01:00| vcpu-0| I120: MsgHint: msg.monitorEvent.tripleFault
2016-01-14T17:30:00.613+01:00| vcpu-0| I120+ A fault has occurred causing a virtual CPU to enter the shutdown state. If this fault had occurred outside of a virtual machine, it would have caused the physical machine to restart. The shutdown state can be reached by incorrectly configuring the virtual machine, a bug in the guest operating system, or a problem in VMware Player.
```

How do I solve this problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this](https://github.com/dthain/basekernel/blob/master/src/kernelcore.S) as a reference.

Comment: You do know when you use use a single operand div like `div ebx` that the dividend is in *edx:eax*.I don't see you zeroing out *edx*. You could use `cwd` instruction right after setting *eax* or `xor edx,edx`. Dividing by 4 can also be done by using the _SHR_ instruction by shifting right 2 bits.

Comment: Anyway, without a minimal complete verifiable example it is difficult to tell what is wrong.

Comment: This is advanced programming, learn to debug first. Especially since I don't see how that `mov` could fault, with interrupts disabled. Just enabling protection should not be a problem until you do something else. The next `jmp` is a better candidate for the fault, possibly due to wrong addressing.

Comment: You also mention `I was debugged by using int 0x16 on every line,` . If you placed an `int 0x16` after switching into protected mode and are trying to call the realmode BIOS interrupt then that in itself could be the source of a problem.

Comment: You are genius! thank you.

Comment: el petch strikes again.